Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)"
Hibernate Error: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [null]
Problem description:
The error occurs during the initialization of the Spring Boot application, specifically when trying to build the Hibernate EntityManager factory. The error log indicates a NullPointerException exception followed by a GenericJDBCException, indicating that Hibernate is unable to open a JDBC connection to perform DDL (Data Definition Language) operations.
Probable cause:
The error appears to be related to the configuration of the connection to the PostgreSQL database. The NullPointerException exception is thrown when Hibernate tries to access the sqlExceptionHelper, but the value returned by JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper() is null. This suggests that the Hibernate configuration may be incomplete or incorrect, especially regarding the definition of the database dialect.

2024-05-24T23:56:19.415+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.m.MotorSportStatsWebAppApplication     : Starting MotorSportStatsWebAppApplication using Java 21.0.1 with PID 19832 (C:\Users\bruno\Desktop\ESCOLA\porg3\MotorSports-Stats\MotorSportStats-WebApp\target\classes started by bruno in C:\Users\bruno\Desktop\ESCOLA\porg3\MotorSports-Stats)
2024-05-24T23:56:19.420+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.m.MotorSportStatsWebAppApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-24T23:56:19.486+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-05-24T23:56:19.487+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2024-05-24T23:56:20.157+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-05-24T23:56:20.175+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-05-24T23:56:20.692+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-05-24T23:56:20.706+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-05-24T23:56:20.706+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.20]
2024-05-24T23:56:20.754+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-05-24T23:56:20.755+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1266 ms
2024-05-24T23:56:20.925+01:00  WARN 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager  : Found explicit default persistence unit with name 'default' in persistence.xml - overriding local default persistence unit settings ('managedTypes', 'packagesToScan' or 'mappingResources')
2024-05-24T23:56:20.948+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-05-24T23:56:21.013+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.4.Final
2024-05-24T23:56:21.048+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-05-24T23:56:21.332+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-05-24T23:56:21.358+01:00  WARN 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.motorsportstatswebapp.MotorSportStatsWebAppApplication.main(MotorSportStatsWebAppApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]

2024-05-24T23:56:21.383+01:00  WARN 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: PostgreSQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-05-24T23:56:22.459+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-05-24T23:56:22.480+01:00  WARN 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2024-05-24T23:56:22.480+01:00 ERROR 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : null
2024-05-24T23:56:22.485+01:00 ERROR 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [null] [n/a]
2024-05-24T23:56:22.485+01:00  WARN 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [null] [n/a]
2024-05-24T23:56:22.487+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-05-24T23:56:22.500+01:00  INFO 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-05-24T23:56:22.518+01:00 ERROR 19832 --- [MotorSportStats-WebApp] [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [null] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.motorsportstatswebapp.MotorSportStatsWebAppApplication.main(MotorSportStatsWebAppApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [null] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [null] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext.getQueryResults(ExtractionContext.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 23 common frames omitted

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.Notificacao</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.NotificacaoUtilizador</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.Utilizador</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.TipoUtilizador</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.Favorito</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.Competicao</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.TipoCompeticao</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.ResultadoPilotoId</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.PilotoFavoritoId</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.NotificacaoUtilizadorId</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.EquipaFavoritoId</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.EquipaCompeticaoId</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.Equipa</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.CorridaVolta</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.CorridaStage</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.CompeticaoFavoritoId</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.Resultado</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.ResultadoPiloto</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.ResultadoPilotoId</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.CompeticaoFavorito</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.Corrida</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.EquipaCompeticao</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.EquipaFavorito</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.Piloto</class>
        <class>org.motorsportstatscore.entity.PilotoFavorito</class>

        <!-- Configurações de propriedades -->
        <properties>
            <!-- Configuração de conexão com o banco de dados -->
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Projeto"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <!-- Configurações do provedor JPA (Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc.) -->
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.provider" value="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>

            <!-- Configurações específicas do Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.application.name=MotorSportStats-WebApp
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Projeto
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1893
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.boot.allow_jdbc_metadata_access = false
spring.sql.init.mode=never
spring.datasource.hikari.allow-pool-suspension=true

I wanted to start my program and I get this error

If you update this configuration to true, it should solve your problem:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.boot.allow_jdbc_metadata_access

